# Ace Editor - Go to line

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying a fairly simple operation with Ace Editor: having the editor jump to a particular line. I can't get it to work, though!

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9Tb/

```
var editor = ace.edit('editor');

editor.scrollToLine(50, true, true, function () {});
    // Doesn't do anything at all

editor.gotoLine(50, 10, true);
    // Will move the caret to the line, but it will not scroll
    // to the editor to the line if it's off screen
```

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the current version of Ace Editor. If you manually call `editor.resize(true)`, it will recalculate the height and the scrolling functions work correctly:

```
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
editor.resize(true);

editor.scrollToLine(50, true, true, function () {});

editor.gotoLine(50, 10, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9Tb/1/

Comment: this too unfortunately seems to be broken in the latest version (v1.2.6)